# Text positions in imported Dia flow charts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I just finished a flow chart in Dia and want to import it into a latex document. In order to achieve that I exported the dia file into a *.tex and \input{*} it. Looks good, except for all texts are misaligned slightly, see attachments. Is there an easy way to fix this? (I am a latex beginner and would prefer an understandable fix instead of complicated redefinitions of packages if that was possible).

Heres the entire tex file of the flow chart:

```
% Graphic for TeX using PGF
% Title: /home/jakob/Dropbox/Uni/MA/meltSettlingFoam.dia
% Creator: Dia v0.97.2
% CreationDate: Wed Feb 19 11:34:19 2014
% For: jakob
% \usepackage{tikz}
% The following commands are not supported in PSTricks at present
% We define them conditionally, so when they are implemented,
% this pgf file will use them.
\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftransformxscale{1.000000}
\pgftransformyscale{-1.000000}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-46.201247\du}{7.989236\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.958371\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{0.979186\du}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-46.201247\du}{7.989236\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.958371\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{0.979186\du}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201247\du,8.184236\du){Start};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-52.201318\du,10.510051\du)--(-52.201318\du,13.510051\du)--(-40.201318\du,13.510051\du)--(-40.201318\du,10.510051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-52.201318\du,10.510051\du)--(-52.201318\du,13.510051\du)--(-40.201318\du,13.510051\du)--(-40.201318\du,10.510051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201318\du,11.805051\du){Initialisieren Startbedingungen, };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201318\du,12.605051\du){Stoff- und Lösungsparameter};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-49.966318\du,15.010051\du)--(-49.966318\du,17.010051\du)--(-42.436318\du,17.010051\du)--(-42.436318\du,15.010051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-49.966318\du,15.010051\du)--(-49.966318\du,17.010051\du)--(-42.436318\du,17.010051\du)--(-42.436318\du,15.010051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201318\du,16.205051\du){Neuer Zeitschritt};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-53.442418\du,18.510051\du)--(-53.442418\du,20.510051\du)--(-38.960231\du,20.510051\du)--(-38.960231\du,18.510051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-53.442418\du,18.510051\du)--(-53.442418\du,20.510051\du)--(-38.960231\du,20.510051\du)--(-38.960231\du,18.510051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201325\du,19.705051\du){Aufstellen der Geschwindigkeitsgleichung};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-54.201318\du,22.010051\du)--(-54.201318\du,24.010051\du)--(-38.201318\du,24.010051\du)--(-38.201318\du,22.010051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-54.201318\du,22.010051\du)--(-54.201318\du,24.010051\du)--(-38.201318\du,24.010051\du)--(-38.201318\du,22.010051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201318\du,23.205051\du){Aufstellen und Lösen der Enthalpieerhaltung};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-55.131118\du,25.510051\du)--(-55.131118\du,27.510051\du)--(-37.271431\du,27.510051\du)--(-37.271431\du,25.510051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-55.131118\du,25.510051\du)--(-55.131118\du,27.510051\du)--(-37.271431\du,27.510051\du)--(-37.271431\du,25.510051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201275\du,26.705051\du){Lösen der Temperatur-Flüssigphasenanteil-Kopplung};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-46.201271\du,29.010051\du)--(-42.168423\du,31.026474\du)--(-46.201271\du,33.042898\du)--(-50.234118\du,31.026474\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201271\du,29.010051\du)--(-42.168423\du,31.026474\du)--(-46.201271\du,33.042898\du)--(-50.234118\du,31.026474\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201271\du,31.221474\du){Konvergiert?};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-52.759218\du,34.510051\du)--(-52.759218\du,36.510051\du)--(-39.643281\du,36.510051\du)--(-39.643281\du,34.510051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-52.759218\du,34.510051\du)--(-52.759218\du,36.510051\du)--(-39.643281\du,36.510051\du)--(-39.643281\du,34.510051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201250\du,35.705051\du){Lösen der Navier-Stokes-Gleichungen};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-55.329718\du,49.010051\du)--(-55.329718\du,51.010051\du)--(-37.072843\du,51.010051\du)--(-37.072843\du,49.010051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-55.329718\du,49.010051\du)--(-55.329718\du,51.010051\du)--(-37.072843\du,51.010051\du)--(-37.072843\du,49.010051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201281\du,50.205051\du){Berechnen der Absinkgeschwindikeit aus Kräftebilanz};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-54.247818\du,52.510051\du)--(-54.247818\du,54.510051\du)--(-38.154693\du,54.510051\du)--(-38.154693\du,52.510051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-54.247818\du,52.510051\du)--(-54.247818\du,54.510051\du)--(-38.154693\du,54.510051\du)--(-38.154693\du,52.510051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201256\du,53.705051\du){Berechnen und Ausgabe Wärmebilanz};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-46.201258\du,38.010051\du)--(-41.760598\du,40.010051\du)--(-46.201258\du,42.010051\du)--(-50.641918\du,40.010051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201258\du,38.010051\du)--(-41.760598\du,40.010051\du)--(-46.201258\du,42.010051\du)--(-50.641918\du,40.010051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201258\du,40.205051\du){3 Iterationen?};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-46.201248\du,43.510051\du)--(-41.794777\du,45.510051\du)--(-46.201248\du,47.510051\du)--(-50.607718\du,45.510051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201248\du,43.510051\du)--(-41.794777\du,45.510051\du)--(-46.201248\du,47.510051\du)--(-50.607718\du,45.510051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201248\du,45.705051\du){2 Iterationen?};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (-46.201310\du,56.010051\du)--(-40.456501\du,58.010051\du)--(-46.201310\du,60.010051\du)--(-51.946118\du,58.010051\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201310\du,56.010051\du)--(-40.456501\du,58.010051\du)--(-46.201310\du,60.010051\du)--(-51.946118\du,58.010051\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201310\du,58.205051\du){Letzter Zeitschritt?};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-46.201231\du}{62.497294\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.974487\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{0.987244\du}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{-46.201231\du}{62.497294\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.974487\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{0.987244\du}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (-46.201231\du,62.692294\du){Ende};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201265\du,9.018490\du)--(-46.201291\du,10.461016\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201318\du,13.558879\du)--(-46.201318\du,14.961222\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201320\du,17.059794\du)--(-46.201323\du,18.460307\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201323\du,20.559794\du)--(-46.201320\du,21.960307\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201305\du,24.059794\du)--(-46.201288\du,25.460307\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201274\du,27.560318\du)--(-46.201272\du,28.960052\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201261\du,33.092894\du)--(-46.201254\du,34.494240\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201252\du,36.558146\du)--(-46.201254\du,37.960052\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201254\du,42.060049\du)--(-46.201252\du,43.460052\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201263\du,47.560039\du)--(-46.201273\du,48.961955\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201273\du,51.059794\du)--(-46.201263\du,52.460307\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201268\du,54.558146\du)--(-46.201285\du,55.960062\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-46.201274\du,60.059903\du)--(-46.201249\du,61.460386\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{0.000000\du}{0.000000\du}}\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-42.118423\du,31.019977\du)--(-35.881118\du,31.010051\du)--(-35.881118\du,23.010051\du)--(-38.152520\du,23.010051\du);
}}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-47.881118\du,40.010051\du){};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{0.000000\du}{0.000000\du}}\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-41.710598\du,40.010051\du)--(-35.881118\du,40.010051\du)--(-35.881118\du,35.510051\du)--(-39.593695\du,35.510051\du);
}}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{0.000000\du}{0.000000\du}}\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-41.744777\du,45.510051\du)--(-34.881118\du,45.510051\du)--(-34.881118\du,19.510051\du)--(-38.909934\du,19.510051\du);
}}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{0.000000\du}{0.000000\du}}\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (-51.996118\du,58.010051\du)--(-56.881118\du,58.010051\du)--(-56.881118\du,16.010051\du)--(-50.016557\du,16.010051\du);
}}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-39.881118\du,31.010051\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-40.881118\du,30.857551\du){nein};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-46.201258\du,33.641067\du){  ja};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-39.881118\du,40.010051\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-39.881118\du,40.010051\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-40.881118\du,39.857551\du){nein};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-46.201253\du,42.607551\du){  ja};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-45.881118\du,60.010051\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-46.201261\du,60.607644\du){  ja};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-54.881118\du,57.857551\du){nein};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-46.201268\du,48.108497\du){  ja};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-40.881118\du,46.010051\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (-40.881118\du,45.357551\du){nein};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Dia excerpt]

[image: Latex result]

Comment: It is easier to draw it by your self, than adjusting this. It is low level pgf code and the node borders are drawn separately. To adjust you have to change the coordinates like: `\node[anchor=west] at (-40.881118\du,39.557551\du){nein};` instead of `\node[anchor=west] at (-40.881118\du,30.857551\du){nein};`. Hope you can do it your self.

Comment: I've run into the same thing yesterday.
If you're willing to compile dia for yourself, this bug seems to be fixed in the version currently available from dia's git repository.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with diagrams made with Dia is that the text is not placed relative to any nodes or lines. I have the same problems sometimes. My work-around is to edit the *.tex file manually.

Check out http://www.texample.net, there you can find examples of flow charts and lots of other things. Most of these examples build the flow chart using a relative placement of nodes. In that case, the texts will never show any misalignment.

To fix your problem, you could do the following.

Identify the node containing "Konvergiert?", give this node a name, and change the node definition of the node containing "nein" to a placement relative to the node "Konvergiert?". Unfortunately, Dia can't do this on its own, at least I can't do it with Dia.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late answer ; I finally found a solution to this problem, and wanted to share with all...

You just have to include a `\tikzstyle{every node}=[yshift=4pt]` just before your `\input`.

Of course, you may tweak the 4pt to your needs...

Comment: You should use `\tikzset` not `\tikzstyle`. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles.