# Adjust alignment of text inside TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

A block diagram is generated with `tikz pfg` via [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/).
However, the text inside the blocks is misaligned vertically. This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161251/text-positions-in-imported-dia-flow-charts) says that it is impossible to do from Dia. So, how can following diagram be aligned with the text inside the boxes manually by editing in generated Tikz file.
I use, LuaTex with TexLive.
[image]
**MWE**

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%\overfullrule=1mm
\documentclass[11pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn,conference]{IEEEtran} 

%\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
%\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
%\usepackage[]{layout}


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath} 
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}

%\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[obeyDraft,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor=Green4,
    linkcolor  = blue
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%SPECIAL FONT INITILIZATION


\pagebreak


% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
% \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
% \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
% or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
% will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
% driver is specified.
% \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
% \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphicx was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at: 



% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        %   \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \input{tikzpic.tex}
        \caption{My caption}
        \label{f02}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**TIKZ Picture**

```
% Graphic for TeX using PGF
\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=4 in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\pgftransformxscale{0.557193}
\pgftransformyscale{-0.557193}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (18.042970\du,27.000000\du)--(18.042970\du,31.000000\du)--(23.257030\du,31.000000\du)--(23.257030\du,27.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (18.042970\du,27.000000\du)--(18.042970\du,31.000000\du)--(23.257030\du,31.000000\du)--(23.257030\du,27.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (20.650000\du,28.440000\du){Abcdef};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (20.650000\du,29.240000\du){ghij};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (20.650000\du,30.040000\du){ klmn};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (4.000000\du,21.000000\du)--(4.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(9.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(9.000000\du,21.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (4.000000\du,21.000000\du)--(4.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(9.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(9.000000\du,21.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (6.500000\du,22.840000\du){Abcdef ghijkl };
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (6.500000\du,23.640000\du){Abcdef ghijkl};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (12.000000\du,21.000000\du)--(12.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(17.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(17.000000\du,21.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (12.000000\du,21.000000\du)--(12.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(17.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(17.000000\du,21.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (14.500000\du,22.840000\du){Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (14.500000\du,23.640000\du){Abcdef ghijkl};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (20.000000\du,21.000000\du)--(20.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(25.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(25.000000\du,21.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (20.000000\du,21.000000\du)--(20.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(25.000000\du,25.000000\du)--(25.000000\du,21.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (22.500000\du,22.840000\du){Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (22.500000\du,23.640000\du){Abcdef ghijkl};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\fill (10.031720\du,27.000000\du)--(10.031720\du,31.000000\du)--(15.268280\du,31.000000\du)--(15.268280\du,27.000000\du)--cycle;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (10.031720\du,27.000000\du)--(10.031720\du,31.000000\du)--(15.268280\du,31.000000\du)--(15.268280\du,27.000000\du)--cycle;
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (12.650000\du,29.240000\du){Abcdef ghijkl};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (9.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(12.000000\du,23.000000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (17.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(20.000000\du,23.000000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (18.042970\du,29.000000\du)--(15.268280\du,29.000000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsstart{latex}
{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{0.000000\du}{0.000000\du}}\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (6.500000\du,25.000000\du)--(6.500000\du,29.000000\du)--(10.031720\du,29.000000\du)--(10.031720\du,29.000000\du);
}}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
{\pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpoint{0.000000\du}{0.000000\du}}\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (25.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(27.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(27.000000\du,29.000000\du)--(23.257030\du,29.000000\du);
}}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\pgfsetarrowsend{latex}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (27.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(29.000000\du,23.000000\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{27.491221\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.197505\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.213670\du}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{27.491221\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.197505\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.213670\du}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (0.886038\du,27.723165\du){$A$};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{30.515687\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.230342\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.246949\du}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{30.515687\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.230342\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.246949\du}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (0.886038\du,30.747631\du){$B$};
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (2.083544\du,21.410867\du)--(4.000000\du,23.000000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (2.083544\du,24.451044\du)--(4.000000\du,23.000000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (2.083544\du,27.491221\du)--(4.000000\du,23.000000\du);
}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.100000\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetbuttcap
{
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
% was here!!!
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\draw (4.000000\du,23.000000\du)--(2.116380\du,30.515687\du);
}
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{21.410867\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.197505\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.213670\du}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{21.410867\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.197505\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.213670\du}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (0.886038\du,21.642811\du){$C$};
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000}
\pgfsetfillcolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{24.451044\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.197505\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.213670\du}}
\pgfusepath{fill}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.099060\du}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetdash{}{0pt}
\pgfsetmiterjoin
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpoint{0.886038\du}{24.451044\du}}{\pgfpoint{1.197505\du}{0\du}}{\pgfpoint{0\du}{1.213670\du}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node at (0.886038\du,24.682988\du){$D$};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (4.000000\du,19.000000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (4.000000\du,19.800000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (4.000000\du,20.600000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (12.000000\du,18.500000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (12.000000\du,19.300000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (12.000000\du,20.100000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (20.125000\du,19.000000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (20.125000\du,19.800000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (20.125000\du,20.600000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (9.050000\du,32.000000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (9.050000\du,32.800000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (18.400000\du,32.000000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (18.400000\du,32.800000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (20.500000\du,32.500000\du){};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (26.500000\du,21.000000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (26.500000\du,21.800000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
% setfont left to latex
\definecolor{dialinecolor}{rgb}{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{dialinecolor}
\node[anchor=west] at (26.500000\du,22.600000\du){\footnotesize Abcdef ghijkl};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
```

Comment: This is really a duplicate of that question and there are not going to be any better answers than those given there. Any programme which exports PGF/TikZ code tends to export code which it is very difficult for humans to edit. If the results are fine, well and good. If not, you are better off writing the code from scratch.

Comment: Basically, what was said [in this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161251/text-positions-in-imported-dia-flow-charts#comment368972_161251) and in the answer to the question you linked. It would be easier to recode the diagram in TikZ. (Even in PGF.) If you want to use this, you must find each node in the code and either redefine the node or manually change the absolute dimensions involved. The nodes are created independently of everything else. Personally, I would either live with the result or abandon the code.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what alignment you are looking for. Because all your nodes have virtually identical content, I don't even really see what is doing what. You have 2 lines in many of the nodes, but the code only seems to include 1 line per node. The alignment in the other question concerns alignment with things outside the node. I don't know if that's what you see as the problem here or not.

Comment: Actually, the same applies to alignment in the node because the 'borders' of the nodes are actually drawn separately, I think. So it is a real mess and completely inflexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated code is unmaintainable.

But your image is very simple to do with TikZ.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draftclsnofoot,onecolumn,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{subcaption}


\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}

%\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[obeyDraft,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage[section]{placeins} 
\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor=Green4,
    linkcolor  = blue
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myarrow/.style={-Triangle}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

%SPECIAL FONT INITILIZATION


\pagebreak


% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
% \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
% \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
% or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
% will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
% driver is specified.
% \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
% \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphicx was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at: 



% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, 
       nodes={text width=1.8cm, text centered, minimum height=1.4cm, anchor=north,
       font=\tiny},
       row 2/.style={nodes={draw, font=\scriptsize}},
       row 3/.style={nodes={draw, font=\scriptsize}},
       ] (mymatr) {
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl &&[-1cm]
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl &&[-1cm]
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl \\[-4pt]
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl &&
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl &&
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl \\[30pt]
       & Abcdef ghijkl && {Abcdef\\ ghij\\ klmn} \\[-6pt]
       & Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl &&  
       Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl \\
       };
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, 
       nodes={
         draw,
         text width=.4cm, text centered,
         circle,
         font=\small\itshape}, 
       row sep=7pt,
       left= of mymatr] (circlematr) {
       C\\
       D\\
       A\\
       B\\
       };
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
      \draw (circlematr-\i-1) -- (mymatr-2-1.west);
    \draw[myarrow] (mymatr-2-1) -- (mymatr-2-3);
    \draw[myarrow] (mymatr-2-3) -- (mymatr-2-5);
    \draw[myarrow] (mymatr-2-5) -- node[above=-4pt, font=\tiny,text width=1.8cm, text centered, minimum height=1.4cm,] {Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl Abcdef ghijkl}  +(3,0);
    \draw[myarrow] (mymatr-2-5) ++(2,0) |- (mymatr-3-4);
    \draw[myarrow] (mymatr-3-4) -- (mymatr-3-2);
    \draw[myarrow] (mymatr-3-2) -| (mymatr-2-1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{My caption}\label{f02}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After 6 years, finally :) Thank you anyways.

Comment: @kaka I was searching for unanswered questions. You're welcome!